# yq update yaml array using other yaml file's array

Tags: yaml, yq

I dont have any detail knowledge on yq.
template1.yaml

```
spec:
 template:
   temp:
    vars:
      - name: first
        env: []
```

template2.yaml

```
env:
 -name: "first"
  value: 1
 -name: "two"
  value: 2
```

I want to add env array of template2.yaml to template1.yaml's env array using yq. How can we do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Which tool called yq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) are you using?

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (tested with v4.20.2):

```bash
yq '
  .spec.template.temp.vars[].env += load("template2.yaml").env
' template1.yaml
```

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (tested with v3.0.2):

```bash
yq -y '
  .spec.template.temp.vars[].env += input.env
' template1.yaml template2.yaml
```

Output:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    temp:
      vars:
        - name: first
          env:
            - name: "first"
              value: 1
            - name: "two"
              value: 2
```

Note: This assumes, your `template2.yaml` looks more like this:

```yaml
env:
  - name: "first"
    value: 1
  - name: "two"
    value: 2
```